# Does Raspberry Pi 3 B+ support the RGB-D Sensor?

Tags: pi-3b+, sensor, computer-vision

Currently I am using Pi Camera which capture the image.

But my objective is **: To find the nearest object from the camera image. But Image Contains multiple objects shown below**

[image: FindClosestobject]

**RGB-D can capture the image and also find the depth of image using IR sensor.** Can i purchase the RGB-D sensor ?

Does Raspberry pi support RGB-D sensor?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: probably, depends on the sensor

Comment: what is "the RGB-D sensor" - do you have a specific one in mind?

Comment: Depth sensing devices that work in association with a RGB camera, that will provide the depth information of conventional image on per-pixel basis. e.g 1) Intel Real Sense Series 2) Microsoft Kinect V2. @JaromandaX